# Google tag manager dependency in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, google-tag-manager

When I added gradle dependency to google tag manager, I have got error.

```
debugUnitTestCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: debugUnitTest
Dependency resolved to an incompatible version: Dependency(fromArtifactVersion=ArtifactVersion(groupId=com.google.firebase, artifactId=firebase-mess
aging, version=18.0.0), toArtifact=Artifact(groupId=com.google.firebase, artifactId=firebase-iid), toArtifactVersionString=[18.0.0])

> Task :app:dependencies FAILED
```

I tried another version of tag-manager dependecny, but still not working. I understand that a problem with dependencies versions, but I dont know how can I solve it.

my gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:17.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is output from flutter doctor -v

```
   [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Linux, locale cs_CZ.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 at /usr/lib/flutter
    • Framework revision 20e59316b8 (10 days ago), 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
    • Engine revision fee001c93f
    • Dart version 2.4.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /home/kleinpetr/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.1
    • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 35.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1)
    • IntelliJ at /opt/idea-IU-191.7479.19
    • Flutter plugin version 36.0.4
    • Dart plugin version 191.7479.14

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Pixel • FA77T0304661 • android-arm64 • Android Q (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

And this is output from gradlew app:dependencies

```
debugRuntimeClasspath - Resolved configuration for runtime for variant: debug
+--- androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0
+--- project :firebase_core
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.5.0
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:16.5.0
|    |         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0
|    |         |    |    \--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    \--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |         \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |         +--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    \--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |         +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    |    |    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    |    |    |    \--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    |    |    \--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    \--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    |    \--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    +--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         |    |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    \--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0
|    |         |    |         |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |         \--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0
|    |         |    |              +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |         |    |              +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |              +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |              +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |         |    |              +--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |              \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.5.0] -> 16.5.0
|    |         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0 (*)
|    |         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:[16.5.0] -> 16.5.0
|    |         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0
|    |         |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.2.0 (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0 (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.5.0] -> 16.5.0 (*)
|    |         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1
|    |         |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.2.0 (*)
|    |         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.5.0
|    |         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0 (*)
|    |         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.5.0] -> 16.5.0 (*)
|    |         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:[16.5.0] -> 16.5.0 (*)
|    |         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:[16.5.0] -> 16.5.0
|    |         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0 (*)
|    |         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.5.0] -> 16.5.0 (*)
|    |         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1
|    |         |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.2.0 (*)
|    |         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.3 -> 17.0.0
|    |         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.2.0 (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |         |    |    \--- com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.3
|    |         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.1.2 -> 18.0.0
|    |         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.2.0 (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1 (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |         |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:17.0.0 (*)
|    |         |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.1
|    |         |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1
|    |         |    |         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.2.0 (*)
|    |         |    |         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |         |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.2.0 (*)
|    |         |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:17.0.1
|    |         |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.2.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:16.5.0
|    |              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.2.0 (*)
|    |              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.5.0] -> 16.5.0 (*)
|    |              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:[16.5.0] -> 16.5.0 (*)
|    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:[16.5.0] -> 16.5.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.1.0 -> 17.0.0 (*)
+--- project :image_picker
|    \--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0 (*)
+--- project :flutter_local_notifications
|    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.1 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2
+--- project :file_picker
|    \--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01 -> 1.0.0
|         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|         +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|         +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 (*)
|         +--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0 (*)
|         +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0 (*)
|         +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 (*)
|         +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0
|         |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|         |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|         \--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0
|              +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0 (*)
|              \--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 (*)
+--- project :vibration
+--- project :keyboard_visibility
+--- project :image_picker_saver
|    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
+--- project :connectivity
+--- project :fluttertoast
|    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2 (*)
+--- project :image_downloader
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.21
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.21
|    |         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.21
|    |         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.1 -> 1.0.2 (*)
+--- project :contacts_service
+--- project :share
+--- project :permission_handler
|    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2
|    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2 (*)
+--- project :uni_links
+--- project :firebase_messaging
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.2.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:17.0.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[18.0.0] -> 18.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:17.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.1.0 -> 17.0.0 (*)
|    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    \--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0 (*)
+--- project :device_id
+--- project :image_gallery_saver
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.20 -> 1.3.21 (*)
+--- project :shared_preferences
+--- project :flutter_facebook_login
|    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.39.0
|         +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.39.0
|         |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|         |    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         |    |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|         |    |         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|         |    \--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0 (*)
|         +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-common:4.39.0
|         |    +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.39.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0
|         |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0 (*)
|         |    +--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0 (*)
|         |    +--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0
|         |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|         |    \--- androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0
|         |         +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|         |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|         |         +--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0 (*)
|         |         +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0 (*)
|         |         \--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 (*)
|         \--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0 (*)
+--- project :sqflite
+--- project :path_provider
+--- project :firebase_analytics
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.5.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.1.0 -> 17.0.0 (*)
+--- project :url_launcher
+--- project :multi_image_picker
|    +--- androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0
|    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    +--- com.sangcomz:FishBun:0.10.0
|    |    +--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3
|    |    |    \--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:1.1.3
|    |    +--- com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0
|    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.transition:transition:1.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0
|    |    |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|    |    |         +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2 (*)
|    |    |         \--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 (*)
|    |    \--- androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0
|         +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:gifdecoder:4.9.0
|         |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.0.2
|         +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:disklrucache:4.9.0
|         +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.9.0
|         +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0 (*)
|         \--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0 (*)
+--- project :google_sign_in
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:16.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:16.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.2.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1 -> 16.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0
+--- project :flutter_sms
+--- project :flutter_statusbarcolor
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.21 (*)
\--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3 -> androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0

debugRuntimeElements - Runtime elements for debug (n)
No dependencies

debugRuntimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for 'debug' sources. (n)
No dependencies

debugUnitTestAnnotationProcessorClasspath - Resolved configuration for annotation-processor for variant: debugUnitTest
No dependencies

debugUnitTestCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: debugUnitTest
Dependency resolved to an incompatible version: Dependency(fromArtifactVersion=ArtifactVersion(groupId=com.google.firebase, artifactId=firebase-mess
aging, version=18.0.0), toArtifact=Artifact(groupId=com.google.firebase, artifactId=firebase-iid), toArtifactVersionString=[18.0.0])

> Task :app:dependencies FAILED
         *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of connectivity will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See ... for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: update all firebase dependancy version to latest in yaml file, than try again

Answer (score 0):

Add this below your gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

after this

```
// Work around for googletagmanager-gradle-plugin compatibility
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```